# MySQL result Group by two values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need some help for a query to group some rows, I'm trying the whole day and find no solution and I'm sure it's easy. Maybe some one can bring me light in the dark:

My Table:

```
id | Bid | Cid | value
 4 | 22  | 11  | 33
 5 | 24  | 11  | 33
 6 | 25  | 11  | 33
 7 | 24  | 11  | 100
 8 | 25  | 16  | 150
```

I want only the result **Bid=25** if I have **Cid 11, 16** and **value 33, 150**

I tried

```
SELECT id, Bid
FROM `table`
WHERE
    Cid IN (11, 16) AND
    value IN ('33','150')
GROUP BY Bid;
```

But in this case I get all possible Cid's ...

It seems I'm on a wood way.

Comment: do you want to check if a bid has both (cid, value) pairs (11, 33) and (16, 150)?

Comment: yes, exactly both need to match

Comment: Hi @Korty , why do you want Bid=25 alone in the output ? If you can specify some relation that you are trying to bring with this query, that would be helpful. And groupby didn’t work because it will consolidate all the rows that are having same value of Bid into a single row in the output.

Comment: Bid=25 help me to get the name of a row in another table.

Comment: with Cid 11 and value 33 AND Cid 16 and value 150 AND (maybe) Cid 11 and value 55 ... no limit of combination (20 - 25 combinations possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is tricky because you are looking for the presence of pairs of column values in a given group.  One way to go here is to aggregate by `Bid`, `Cid`, and `value`, first, with the restriction that each record has a matching pair.  Then subquery this by `Bid` and check that the count be 2, indicating that both pairs were present.

```
SELECT Bid
FROM
(
    SELECT Bid, Cid, value
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE (Cid, value) IN ((11, 33), (16, 150))
    GROUP BY Bid, Cid, value
) t
GROUP BY Bid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

### Demo

Since you are using SQL Server we can slightly refactor the above query to this:

```
SELECT Bid
FROM
(
    SELECT Bid, Cid, value
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE (Cid = 11 AND value = 33) OR (Cid = 16 AND value = 150)
    GROUP BY Bid, Cid, value
) t
GROUP BY Bid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: In your example it works!! but if i take it 1:1 (i proved !!) I get an error: Near ',' a nonboolean expression was specified in a context where a condition is expected.

Comment: @Korty Both of the answers given are running without error in their respective demos.  I think the problem is on your end.  If my demo fails for certain data, then fork my Rextester and show me the problem.

Comment: Really? This is the kind of thing we're encouraging now? :-(

Comment: @Tim it was too late yesterday, I found my mistake: I use MS sql not MySQL so the syntax is a bit different. Do you have experiences with this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fad5c/3

Comment: @Korty I updated my answer with a version of the query which runs on SQL Server.  Actually, my second query is ANSI compliant and should run on just about any database.

Comment: your syntax changes are right: http://rextester.com/JEYHN58429 in this case the MSsql query works and filter both values right

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer when you use GROUP BY in combination with some SUM

```
SELECT
 Bid
FROM 
 Table1 
GROUP BY
 Bid
HAVING 
   SUM(Cid = 11) AND SUM(Cid = 16) 
 AND
   SUM(value = 33) AND SUM(value = 150)
```

**Result**

```
| Bid |
|-----|
|  25 |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce56e97/2

Comment: it works in your example, but I get following error: Wrong syntax near ')'. I proved it more then on time - phpMyAdmin specials?

Comment: I found my mistake, it was too late yesterday, I use MS sql not MySQL so it seems a syntax error is my issue. Do you have experiences with this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fad5c/3